# Variable is null in console

Tags: javascript, facebook

So, I get a variable throught Facebook FQL, and in some cases it's `null`. Even if I try to avoid the null parts, in console it still returns null values. I have something like this, so when the variable is null, it will display a fallback.

```
if(group[i].pic_cover) {
    groupcover.src = group[i].pic_cover.source;                   
} else {
    groupcover.src = "../images/noimg.png"; 
}
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

You're not checking if `.source` is falsy, just if `.pic_cover` is. Perhaps you meant to check all of it.

```
if(group[i] && group[i].pic_cover && group[i].pic_cover.source) {
    groupcover.src = group[i].pic_cover.source; 
} else{
    groupcover.src = "../images/noimg.png"; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using typeof

```
if(typeof group[i].pic_cover !='null')
                    {
                        groupcover.src = group[i].pic_cover.source; 

                    }
                    else{
                       groupcover.src = "../images/noimg.png"; 
                    }
```

Comment: When is `typeof group[i].pic_cover` ever falsy?

Comment: `typeof x` is never `'null'`. Not until ES6.